# How to send new lines from file to a tcp port?

Tags: filesystems, pipe, tcp, tail, nc

Wait for file changes and send new lines to a TCP port server.

I've tried

nc 127.0.0.1 1234 -c "tail -F /var/log/changes.log" &

But get broken pipe

Comment: better. go for flume in production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know which version of netcat you are using, but mine does not have a `-c` parameter. However, `tail -F /var/log/changes.log | nc 127.0.0.1 1234` works for me.